# Removing certain elements from an array that fit a condition

Tags: arrays, matlab, diff

How to remove elements from an array that have difference of 3 or less between subsequent elements? For example

```
A=[3 6 10 14 17 20]
```

to this

```
B=[3 10 14 20]
```

I believe I can use `diff` but in what context should I use it to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `diff` and then compare this to 3. You can then construct a logical array (that includes the first value by default) and use this to index into `A`.

```
tokeep = [true, diff(A) > 3];
B = A(tokeep);
```

In your example though, the difference between 17 and 20 is 3 so that would remove 20.